# How to create a 'fresh' session when the page is re-opened

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-web-developer-2010

I am very new to basic programming, and I'm currently creating a webpage that handles bookings and when the booking has been made, it stores the $ value of the booking and the amount of the booking in session variables. How do I make it so that when the page has been exited and then re-opened the values get re-set? I have a clear button that does this manually but is it possible to do it automatically?

Cheers

Comment: You would have to reset the Session variable in your method that gets called when your page loads.

Comment: Do you mean that if the user closes their browser it should start a new session if they return?  It's unclear what you mean by *when the page has been exited*.

Comment: @Yuck One would think the only way this is relevant is on the return of a response after processing the request, GET or POST. How else would you define it in order to bring confusion/ambiguity?

Comment: @Yuck Yes, that's what I mean, the; if(!IsPostBack) works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Session.Abandon()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx) when you're done.

> Once the Abandon method is called, the current session is no longer valid and a new session can be started. Abandon causes the `End` event to be raised. A new `Start` event will be raised on the next request.

Comment: Using `Session.Abandon` is probably overkill in this scenario and actually bad advice, as the OP just wants to remove `Session` values pertinent to bookings. As you know, `Session` could contain a lot more than just this and `Session.Abandon` will kill it all.

Comment: @KarlAnderson Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: Where would you put this in my code? At the end of Page_Load?

Comment: @AshleyKrynen That could work, or at the end of a logic which wants to conclude with this scenario, such as the end of a button click event or whatnot.

Comment: KarlAnderson is right. This will kill all the sessions. You can do it by adding the following block of code to page_load event handler. if(!page.IsPostBack){ Session["BookingInfo"] = null; }

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli You're wrong, it will abandon the _current_ session, not _all_ sessions.

Comment: @GrantThomas Let say you have three sessions opened Session["user"] , Session["BookingInfo"], Session["blabla"] ,, now which one it will close?

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli You evidently don't understand the Session... all of your examples use _the same session_. You can't have three sessions per user like that. It doesn't work that way. You have _one_ session with _three_ values.

Comment: @GrantThomas: Whatever but i need to keep the two and kill one.

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli Then you're not _killing_ anything, just blotting our the data stored in one key/value pair of a session that will remain very much "alive."

Comment: @GrantThomas Ok, Just tell me if want to keep Session["User"] and refresh the other one. How can i do it.

Comment: @GrantThomas I'm having a slight problem, I have the Session.Abandon(); in there but as I have 2 pages, when I go in between each of them it either wipes the data before I have exited, or does nothing at all...

Comment: do it like this man .. Grant Thomas answer is not good one.  You can do it by adding the following block of code to page_load event handler. if(!Page.IsPostBack){ Session["BookingInfo"] = null; }

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli I've tried that, but kicks up this error: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Comment: so put a if condition if(Session["BookingInfo"] != null){ Session["BookingInfo"] = null;}

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli Your claim that this is not a good answer is a bad one.

Comment: Would just be easier if there was a: if(browserIsExited){clears session} haha. The only problem is the data is still stored and visible when the browser is exited and then re-opened

Comment: @AshleyKrynen :  if(!Page.IsPostBack){ if(Session["BookingInfo"] != null){ Session["BookingInfo"] = null;} } .. this will clear the session when you go to some other page and come back to this page. if you want to clear it after being saved. Put Session["BookingInfo"] = null after the code line that is saving your data.